# How to read files with different formats?

Tags: java

I have a code which read file:

```
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(FILE_PATH);
        byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(resource.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayResource contentsAsResource = new ByteArrayResource(content) {
            @Override
            public String getFilename() {
                return fileName;
            }
        };
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        multiValueMap.add("file", contentsAsResource);
```

after reading the file is sent to another service. if you call the rest method of another service, then both file types are correctly processed (txt and pdf), and if you read from the file (execute the code above) and send it to another service, then pdf does not work (with txt everything is ok)

Addition Info:
I read a file from local directory to byte array and send to another service which converted byte array to file. there is no problem with the txt file when I read the pdf and send the byte array to another service that converts back to pdf, but it does not open (it gives an error)

Comment: It is not clear what your issue is.

Comment: What do you mean, "pdf does not work"? What happens?

Comment: @DavidConrad I updated description of task

Comment: @AlexBrekhin Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Are you able to validate your code on your local machine, i.e. read the file into memory, then write it back into a new file and try opening that file?